# Confused about this NFA sentence

Tags: nfa, automaton

What does "*In these situations the thread of the NFA's existence corresponding to those states simply dies*" mean in my textbook?

Comment: I don't think there is enough context to your quote for us to give you an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the nondeterministic finite automaton with states `A, B, C, D`, input alphabet `{0}`, and the transition function given by

```
canGoFrom(A, 0) = {B, C}
canGoFrom(B, 0) = {}
canGoFrom(C, 0) = {D}
canGoFrom(D, 0) = {}
```

That is, it looks somewhat like this:

```
    A
   / \
  B   C
       \
        D
```

with all edges pointing downwards and having label `0`. Suppose that `D` is the accepting state.

Suppose that you now want to check whether input string `00` is accepted by the automaton.

You start with a single thread, the reading head pointing to first `0`, and in start state `A`. When you read the first zero, the NFA has two transitions it can make, and it must make *all* possible transitions at once, so the thread of NFA's existence splits into two threads: one is now in state `B`, the other is in state `C`.

Now the automaton has to consume the second zero. Because the second thread of existence `canGoFrom(C, 0) = {D}`, it happily transitions from `C` to the accepting state `D`, without splitting any further. However, the first thread of existence `canGoFrom(B, 0) = {}`, that is, it has nowhere to go. In this situation, the first thread of NFA's existence simply dies. It no longer contributes anything to the decision whether the input is accepted or not.

If all threads of existence die, then the input is not accepted.

Here, the second thread of existence reached the accepting state `D`, so the input is accepted.

Comment: thank you so much this has cleared it up for me.  By the way how did you figure it out?  I like using stack overflow for help, but at the same time i want to figure out these problems on my own.  That way i can get "A" letter grades on the tests for this class.

Comment: @ComputerKnight I didn't "figure out" anything, I've just listened enough lectures and read enough books on this topic, so I understand the language that they use. Moreover, this interpretation seems to be the only meaningful in the context of NFAs.

Comment: @ComputerKnight Your question has been locked as "too broad". That means that there will be no more answers. If the above posting answers your questions, you can [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it. Otherwise one should modify the question and vote for reopening.